# How can I save relational data when starting my Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

While starting my application, I want to add data named **ADMIN** and **CUSTOMER** to the Role table. At the same time, I want to create a **USER** and give this **USER** the **ADMIN** role.
But as you can see, when I want to set the role field to the **USER** entity, it gives an error. If I remove the role field assignment on the user entity, it does not give an error. Am I trying to assign this role information to the user without saving it to the database? Do all these transactions happen on a single transaction? What is the problem?

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class AppStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setName("ADMIN");
        Role role2 = new Role();
        role2.setName("CUSTOMER");
        roleRepository.save(role);
        roleRepository.save(role2);

        User user = new User();
        user.setUserStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
        user.setUserType(UserType.ADMIN);
        user.setPhoneNumber("05365785476");
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("123456789e"));
        user.setEmail("emirhan@gmail.com");
        user.setName("Emirhan Ay");
        user.getRoles().add(role);
        user.setCreatedAt(new Date());
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at com.example.bankapp.BankApplication.main(BankApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.bankapp.entity.Role; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.bankapp.entity.Role
```

**UPDATED ! I found a solution like this ->**
I created a data.sql file inside the app/resources folder.
And i added these below settings to my application properties file.

```java
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

```sql
INSERT INTO ROLE (name) VALUES ('ADMIN');
INSERT INTO ROLE (name) VALUES ('CUSTOMER');
INSERT INTO USER (email,password,name,phone_number,user_type,user_status,is_deleted,created_at)
VALUES ('emirhan@gmail.com','$2a$10$ReWLWNLk6iSPWZ1z6tVv1efkk0qgONxAoZaD6BJ8I80qe0ykfLqma',
        'Emirhan Ay','05365785476','ADMIN','ACTIVE','false','2022-06-01 23:27:03.534');
INSERT INTO USER_ROLE (user_id,role_id) VALUES ('1','1')
```

Comment: here's how to initialize the database in spring-boot https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql

Comment: liquibase or something like that is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is actually working, but your error indicates that you're not persisting it properly.  The detached entity is because you're attempting to persist the Role, which hasn't itself been persisted.

Try something like this

...

```
Role persistedRole = roleRepository.save(role);
```

...

```
user.getRoles().add(persistedRole);
```

Also, note that in your current logic, you aren't doing anything with `role2`, but if you want to attach it to your `User` you will need to do the same with it.

As others have mentioned, there's other Spring ways to pre-propulate a database that I would lean to, unless you're going to add logic to ensure that this doesn't recreate these records in the database everytime you start your app.

Comment: I did as you said and still get the same error.

Comment: It seems unlikely that if you are attempting to persist a User with an attached, already persisted, Role would still throw `PersistentObjectException`.  Are you certain that the error is still occurring in the same location?